# 2's complement hex number to decimal in java

Tags: java, hex, twos-complement, negative-number

I have a hex string that represents a 2's complement number. Is there an easy way (libraries/functions) to translate the hex into a decimal without working directly with its bits??

E.G. This is the expected output given the hex on the left:

```
"0000" => 0
"7FFF" => 32767 (max positive number)
"8000" => -32768 (max negative number)
"FFFF" => -1
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you know how to obtain an unsigned number then just subtract 65536 if the value is bigger than 32767

Comment: At first I said Integer.parseInt but then realized its 2's compliment. So I removed my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to trick java into converting the number without forcing a positive result:

```
Integer.valueOf("FFFF",16).shortValue(); // evaluates to -1 (short)
```

Of course this sort of thing only works for 8, 16, 32, and 64-bit 2's complement:

```
Short.valueOf("FF",16).byteValue(); // -1 (byte)
Integer.valueOf("FFFF",16).shortValue(); // -1 (short)
Long.valueOf("FFFFFFFF",16).intValue(); // -1 (int)
new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF",16).longValue(); // -1 (long)
```

[Example here](http://ideone.com/LhHco).

Comment: very interesting! do you know what's actually happening here though? :|

Comment: I'm pretty sure that converting to a lower-precision type simply keeps the lowest bits, so what was a `0000FFFF` `int` becomes a `FFFF` `short`. Similarly `Integer.valueOf("A7FFFF",16).shortValue();` would also result in `-1` -- the higher bits are just cut off.

Comment: You're probably right. Still, I don't fully understand why the sign switches to negative when converting to a lower precision... It probably depends on how numbers are stored internally, I might need to do some research on this..

Comment: Actually it's specified in http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25363

Comment: Particularly "A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value."

Comment: The [`BigInteger` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29) also states that it follows the same convention. So it looks like this behavior is guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this will work all the times. It still feels a little bit as java magic though since the sign information is usually stored in the highest bit and this would certainly be truncated in the conversion. I guess numbers are probably stored/encoded as 2's complement internally even after a narrowing conversion. Integer FFFFFF gets truncated to FFFF (65536) that is way too big for a short (max positive value: 2^15-1=32767). At this point Java just follows the 2's complement encoding and produces -1. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Just write a utility method:

```
 public static Integer twosComp(String str) throws java.lang.Exception {
       Integer num = Integer.valueOf(str, 16);
       return (num > 32767) ? num - 65536 : num;
 }
```

Tests:

```
 twosComp("7FFF") -> 32767
 twosComp("8000") -> -32768
 twosComp("FFFF") -> -1
```

Comment: +1 for writing ur own, but it doesn't work Long or larger values does it?

Comment: +1 Looks like it would be easy enough to roll into a BigInteger implementation for ultimate scalability.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work reasonably well.  It can be fooled by passing it non-standard length strings: "FFF" maps to -1.  Zero padding will correct the fault.

You are not clear on what type return you want, so I have returned `Number`, at whatever size is appropriate.

```
public Number hexToDec(String hex)  {
   if (hex == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("hexToDec: hex String is null.");
   }

   // You may want to do something different with the empty string.
   if (hex.equals("")) { return Byte.valueOf("0"); }

   // If you want to pad "FFF" to "0FFF" do it here.

   hex = hex.toUpperCase();

   // Check if high bit is set.
   boolean isNegative =
      hex.startsWith("8") || hex.startsWith("9") ||
      hex.startsWith("A") || hex.startsWith("B") ||
      hex.startsWith("C") || hex.startsWith("D") ||
      hex.startsWith("E") || hex.startsWith("F");

   BigInteger temp;

   if (isNegative) {
      // Negative number
      temp = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
      BigInteger subtrahend = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(hex.length() * 4);
      temp = temp.subtract(subtrahend);
   } else {
      // Positive number
      temp = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
   }

   // Cut BigInteger down to size.
   if (hex.length() <= 2) { return (Byte)temp.byteValue(); }
   if (hex.length() <= 4) { return (Short)temp.shortValue(); }
   if (hex.length() <= 8) { return (Integer)temp.intValue(); }
   if (hex.length() <= 16) { return (Long)temp.longValue(); }
   return temp;
}
```

Sample output:

```
"33" -> 51
"FB" -> -5
"3333" -> 13107
"FFFC" -> -4
"33333333" -> 53687091
"FFFFFFFD" -> -3
"3333333333333333" -> 3689348814741910323
"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE" -> -2
"33333333333333333333" -> 241785163922925834941235
"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" -> -1
```

Comment: Using BigInteger to convert works great without the 'isNegative' logic you have. All I had to do was to create the BigInteger like you did, then call the byteValue/shortValue/intValue/longValue as appropriate for my desired width, and I got the same results you did. Except...I think your value for "33333333" should be 858993459. That's what I got through Java, and the Windows calculator. Try `System.out.println(new BigInteger("33333333", 16).intValue()+" -> "+53687091);`