# Java, Long.parse binary String

Tags: java, long-integer

Why does this code throw a `NumberFormatException` :

```
String binStr = "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
System.out.println(binStr.length());// =  64
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(binStr, 2));
```

Comment: Re-reading this, it's actually a good question.

Comment: This may be an *interesting* question, but certainly not a [*good* question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>`1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.</strike>

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888969/597657

Consider using [`BigInteger(String val, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String,%20int)) instead.

---

**EDIT:**

OK, this is new for me. It appears that `Integer.parseInt(binaryIntegerString, 2)` and `Long.parseLong(binaryLongString, 2)` parse binary as sign-magnitude not as a 2's-complement.

Comment: You missed what I missed when I first commented ;) It's not *larger* ... it doesn't exist.

Comment: `String binStr = "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
System.out.println(binStr.length());// =  64
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(binStr, 2));`

Comment: That linked answer is wrong, Java represents integers as 2's-complement internally, not sign-magnitude.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You are right. But that's how `parseInt()` handles binary.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Well, that's true in the sense that parseInt/parseLong expect negative numbers to be represented with a "-" character.  But that's got nothing to do with the internal representation!

Answer (score 5):

Because it's out of range.  `1000...000` is 2<sup>63</sup>, but `Long` only goes up to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.

Comment: You missed what I missed when I first commented ;) It's not *larger*, it doesn't exist.

Comment: So after all our discussion, it *should* be `Long.MIN_VALUE` from the bit pattern, but `parseLong` doesn't like that. Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 4):

This is the same for all of `Long`, `Integer`, `Short` and `Byte`. I'll explain with a `Byte` example because it's readable:

```
System.out.println(Byte.MIN_VALUE); // -128
System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE); // 127
String positive =  "1000000"; // 8 binary digits, +128 
String negative = "-1000000"; // 8 binary digits, -128
String plus     = "+1000000"; // 8 binary digits, +128
Byte.parseByte(positive, 2); //will fail because it's bigger than Byte.MAX_VALUE 
Byte.parseByte(negative, 2); //won't fail. It will return Byte.MIN_VALUE
Byte.parseByte(plus, 2);     //will fail because its bigger than Byte.MAX_VALUE
```

The digits are interpreted unsigned, no matter what radix is provided. If you want a negative value, you have to have the minus sign at the beginning of the String. [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) says:

> Parses the string argument as a signed long in the radix specified by
>   the second argument. The characters in the string must all be digits
>   of the specified radix (as determined by whether `Character.digit(char, int)` returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may
>   be an ASCII minus sign `'-' ('\u002D')` to indicate a negative value or
>   an ASCII plus sign `'+' ('\u002B')` to indicate a positive value. The
>   resulting long value is returned.

In order to get `MAX_VALUE` we need:

```
String max  =  "1111111"; // 7 binary digits, +127 
// or
String max2 = "+1111111"; // 7 binary digits, +127
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because Long.parseLong cannot parse two's complement representation. The only way to parse two's complement binary string representation in Java SE is BigInteger:

```
long l = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 2).longValue()
```

this gives expected -9223372036854775808result

Answer (score 2):

Largest long value is actually:

```
0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111b = 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the largest possible long (9223372036854775807 = 2 exp 63 - 1) in binary format. Note the L at the end of the last digit.

```
 long largestLong = 0B0111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111L;
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, this is works for me:

```
String bitStr = "-1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(bitStr, 2));
```

Here is a thing: inside Long.parseLong() code logic is looking for explicit sign first. And respectively to the sign, different limits are used (Long.MAX_VALUE for positive, and Long.MIN_VALUE for negative binary literals). Probably it would be better if this logic looked up first to the eldest bit (0 for positive and 1 for negative numbers)  the sign