# parsing Hexadecimal in Java

Tags: java

taking in account that FFFFFFB2 in HEX is -78 in decimal

Why I have an error with this operacion ?

```
Integer.parseInt("FFFFFFB2", 16)
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at tmp.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: Did you know that the number you are trying to convert is a huge number and is equivalent to 18446744073709552000 in decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> taking in account that FFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2 in HEX is -78 in decimal"

Nope, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2 hex is 18446744073709552000 decimal. You're mistaking hex for 2s complement.

If you want to take a 2s complement bit pattern and convert it into a number, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699695/157247) suggests a trick:

```
long l = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFB2",16).longValue();
```

[And it actually works](http://ideone.com/hk6bqO).

Note I used `BigInteger` and `long`, rather than `long` and `int`, as the number is too big.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> An exception of type NumberFormatException is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> The value represented by the string is not a value of type int.

As already pointed out, your number is not an `int`.